# Is 85C temperature normal for a threadripper CPU as shown in my bios screen?

Tags: temperature, threadripper

My bios temp is showing me 85C for my cpu. Is this normal for an AMD threadripper?

[image]

Comment: You haven't provided enough details about your system or environment for anyone to reliably give you an answer that isn't just an opinion. That being said, if 85ºC is the idle temperature, your cooling system is probably not doing it's job properly.

Comment: After many months. I figured it out. It was due to incompatible ram. even though it would install sometimes, it would just throw you off thinking the ram works. But it needs to be a specific spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it it's, and there are other problems as well!

1. In BIOS/UEFI there is one CPU core running at 100% and 85C for Tctl is kinda high so something between your CPU and the CPU fan is not correct
2. Your CPU fan not even connected (or connected somewhere else than actually should be, **CPU Fan 1 speed** shows N/A RPM).
3. You have only 2 (if you don't use splitter) fans for a High End setup,  600 and 1000 rpm for a Threadripper setup (very low!)

First, read the `[manual][1]` (!**!**) which fan header for which use-case! Change your fan settings to check `Tdie` and go for `Full speed`.
Don't cheap out thermalpaste and don't put too much on the CPU.

Buy more fans for the case (if it's not splitted fans).

If you are using splitter, and you actually have more than 2 fans, then check your thermalpase if it's applied correctly. In this case I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWu2tcm4wL8) video for applying thermalpaste on TR.

If you are done with all these things, download a `stress tester` [example software](https://www.aida64.com/) and check if your CPU can stay <=95C Tctl or <=68C Tdie **at full stress** if not then calibrate your PC (fan speed, re-apply thermalpase) until you don't get good results because you can damage your components with high temperature.

*Tctl = Tdie + 27C*

Edit: grammar

Comment: `"Yes it is, and there are other problems as well!"` <- Should that be, "No it isn't"? OP's question is, is this temp normal. It sounds like you're saying that it **is** a cause for concern but you wrote "Yes it is" (i.e. "Yes, this temp is normal")

Comment: Dang I wanted to write No it's not

Comment: Good catch on the CPU fan, although based on the image alone I believe this user has a laptop rather than a desktop.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Well, ASRock motherboard + Threadripper ... what laptop is that :'D? I'm pretty sure it's Desktop only. Threadripper is HEDT. That's either a Monitor that looks like a laptop's display, or actually a laptop display with custom display controller (so you can use laptop displays as Monitor. I know because my secondary display is from a laptop with a custom display controller 12V VGA)

Comment: Heh... good point! D'oh!